# Nested Group-By (SQL), retaining grouped values

Tags: sql, group-by

I have data structured like so:

```
date    hour    station     dem     imp
2/1/2016     1  station1    dem1    6
2/1/2016     2  station1    dem1    1
2/1/2016     1  station1    dem2    0
2/1/2016     2  station1    dem2    10
2/2/2016     1  station1    dem1    6
2/2/2016     2  station1    dem1    4
2/2/2016     1  station1    dem2    5
2/2/2016     2  station1    dem2    5
2/1/2016     1  station 2   dem1    8
2/1/2016     2  station 2   dem1    1
2/1/2016     1  station 2   dem2    7
2/1/2016     2  station 2   dem2    1
2/2/2016     1  station 2   dem1    8
2/2/2016     2  station 2   dem1    7
2/2/2016     1  station 2   dem2    9
2/2/2016     2  station 2   dem2    0
```

I'd like for it to look like the below:

Imp is calculated by taking: the sum of dems for each hour, then the average of the hours for each day.

```
date         station    imp
2/1/2016     station1   8.5
2/1/2016     station2   8.5
2/2/2016     station1   10.0
2/2/2016     station2   12.0
```

E.g. To get 2/1/2016 and station1; imp = ((6+0) + (10+1))/2

The problem I'm experiencing is I'm not sure how to retain the station values when doing `GROUP BY` on something like `dem` or `hour` or `date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can divide the sum by `count(distinct dem)`, which has the # of unique dem's per date/station pair

```
select date, station, sum(imp) / count(distinct dem)
from mytable
group by date, station
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/17001/1

Comment: perfect, thanks! as i'm a beginner can you explain how the group by with two columns is working? conceptually it's hard for me to visualize. is it basically taking each unique date/station pair and then applying that average formula you wrote?

Comment: @mburke05 yes that's basically it, the `count(distinct dem)` only counts the unique # of dems in the group (2) as opposed to `count(dem)` which would count them all (4)